# Pass value to SQL table's Datetime field

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have one SQL table field with the datatype DateTime.

I need to insert the value to SQL from C#. If I directly insert into the table I use the "2015-07-29 12:35:29.123" format.

But when I try to pass DateTime.Today from C# it shows an error.

How can I convert DateTime.Today to the format "2007-05-08 12:35:29.123"?

Comment: Can you please show your code and error message _exactly_? If your column is _really_ `datetime` that should work.

Comment: @Soner  I got the following Error The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Can you show your `c#` code that you are using to insert? It is a lot easier to tell you what is wrong with the code when we know what it is! If you are using `SqlParameters` then format of the date should not be an issue at all. If you are using string literals, then firstly don't, but the date format `yyyy-MM-dd` is not culture invariant for `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME`, with the dateformat `DMY`, `2015-07-29` will fail as a `DATETIME` because it is trying to convert to the 7th day of the 29th month.

Comment: Mark debugger at  DateTime.Today and see what you are getting. What I can guess from this is that your date time format of your local machine is not proper.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff")`

[This site has great examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) check it out

OR

```
DateTime formated_date;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff";

formated_date = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today.ToString, format, provider);
```

Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

Comment: No, OP said the column is `datetime` typed. That means, it doesn't accept any `string` value.

Comment: I edited the answer. Sorry, I don't know the best way to do it. Maybe you can suggest. ^_^

Answer (score -1):

use this code in the model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Date")]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

but leave out 'display' if you already have a label or field to say to enter the date.

required is basically for validation.

Comment: OP never said he's using any model